# How to raise an event at any given time

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to raise an event at a given time in my windows store app. Now I've done this in desktop apps countless times, and I've used `System.Threading.Timer` in the past and it has worked well, but that class is not available to windows store apps.

I have looked in the documentation and found a class called `DispatchTimer` and although it appears to be what I'm after, correct me if I'm wrong but the docs are lacking. But luckily it's pretty easy to use.

So I tried the `DispatchTimer`, but after using it, I'm not even sure this is what I should be using.

How can I watch for any given time and raise an event when that time is up (in a windows store app)? And do you know of any resources that do this in a metro app?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx) like this:

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
timer.Start();

private void OnTimerTick(object sender, object args)
{
    // Do something with pickup here...
}
```

This will create a timer with intervals of 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @Kristian, how would I pass an object as parameter to the OnTimerTick event? Is that possible? I know we can do it for extension methods...

Comment: What kind of argument would you like to pass? You could in any case use the [`DispatchTimer.Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.tag.aspx) property.

Comment: I need to pass an object of type Pickup, so that when the time has elapsed I know which Pickup the alarm was for. Pickup is a class containing order information.

Comment: I just noticed. DispatchTimer.tag doesn't exist in code behind. Weird.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Kristian, but it says DispatcherTimer does not contain a definition for 'Tag'.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong documentation... They've really made it hard to find the [right documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx), now that there is a separate .NET for Windows Store Apps. It seems you're out of luck on this one.

Answer (score 2):

The `DispatcherTimer` is the way to go. Notice that if you want your app to run in background you must declare that on the app manifest or use Background agents.